# Her complexion was 'beautiful'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective which describes a complexion. I understand that the term `complexion` is primarily used to describe the color of someone's skin. However, I'm looking for a word which says that I find the complexion attractive, without actually specifying any color.

> Her complexion was _____

I'd prefer to avoid any generic positive word like `good`, `great`, `amazing` and the like. The word should be (at least somewhat) specifically applicable to complexion.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/complexion) lists these collocations:

> a dark/pale/light/sallow/ruddy/olive/swarthy/clear complexion

Almost all of them denote some color. `Clear` doesn't (arguably), but it doesn't necessarily connote attractiveness.

For the sake of illustration, I tried "[her complexion was beautiful](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22her%20complexion%20was%20beautiful%22&tbm=bks)" on Google books, which gave has a mere 1500 hits. It doesn't sound right.

Is there a common collocation/turn of phrase I could use here?

Comment: If colors can be beautiful, which they can, why can't complexions?

Comment: @Robusto: Exactly. That's why I was surprised to discover that the expression is so rare. `Beautiful` is my last resort. I'm hoping someone suggests a better term, if one exists.

Comment: Seductive, fetching, charming, enticing—or do you absolutely *need* a cliché?

Comment: @Robusto: It doesn't have to be a cliche, per se. But I would like something that's at least semi-specific to complexion, rather than a word which covers all contexts.

Comment: If you want to say her complexion is attractive why not say exactly that? *Her complexion was attractive*.

Comment: I have never taken 'complexion' to primarily describe skin colour, but rather a combination of the colour, texture, evenness and clarity of colour, shade and tone. Terms relating to the beauty of a complexion relate equally well to any underlying skin colour in my view.

Comment: The problem with a phrase like "her complexion was beautiful" or "her complexion was attractive" or even "her complexion was alluring" is that, while colorful purple prose, none of them actually describe *any* details about the person's complexion - just like how "her complexion was ugly" doesn't describe if she has a scar under her right eye, a blemish on her left cheek, a missing eyebrow with a burn mark over it, or any real details about the person's face.  It's a very...empty phrase.

Comment: @TusharRaj: Any expression like "her complexion was ...." has low results in Google Books. Also, you have to check till the last page; the number that is displayed in the first pages is incorrect. The phrasing "has a ... complexion" sounds better also.

Comment: @Zibbobz: Not giving details is precisely the point here. I want to communicate that I find the complexion attractive even if I can't/won't describe the details. All that matters is that it's beautiful. I'm not writing a medical report; details aren't important. Call it 'purple prose' if you want.

Comment: @ermanen: I realize that putting the adjective last is an unconventional choice here. I made it to emphasize the adjective.

Comment: Additionally, Tushar & @Zibbobz, those details, if desired, can always follow an initial declarative phrase, no?

Comment: @LittleEva True, but things like 'beauty' and 'exquisite'ness are subjective - which is why I'm against them.  If it's clear that it's part of a narrative where the narrative character *does* feel that way though, then it's totally valid.

Comment: **Complexion is not just about color**. *"Complexion refers to the natural color, **texture**, and **appearance** of the skin, especially that of the face."*

Comment: I think the reason you found so few hits is that it's just not that common to talk about complexion, unless you're explaining that it's a reason you find the person attractive, and then you describe the specific quality. People just don't say that they find someone's complexion beautiful, they say that they find the person beautiful or they find their face beautiful.

Comment: 'Not giving details' is the problem, not the solution. You should do some work and describe attributes that would make the reader do some work  and *conclude* that it was beautiful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A common term for what the OP describes is, "Her complexion was **flawless**." (a Google search for *flawless complexion* returned about 1,110,000 results)

> [**flawless**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=flawless+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: without any blemishes or imperfections; perfect. "her brown *flawless* skin"
>
> *synonyms*: perfect, unblemished, unmarked, unimpaired

Comment: +1.  I had considered flawless, but I was saving it for another part of what I'm writing (it's kind of apt there, and I didn't want to be repetetive); but now I think it's the best (and maybe only) choice here. Consider it accepted, unless someone tops it.

Comment: Thanks, Tushar - and you're correct in that you really want to be discriminating in employing terms like "flawless."

Comment: @ermanen - I didn't conduct that search using quotation marks, I simply Googled *flawless complexion*, the figure listed, 1,110,000, was copied/pasted from that search.

Comment: @ermanen - "flawless complexion": About 432,000 results / "her complexion was flawless": About 4,910 results.

Comment: Interestingly, ngrams suggests *perfect complexion* was significantly more popular than *flawless complexion* until only recently.

Comment: You could try synonyms for flawless such as "perfect" or "sublime".

Comment: @PointlessSpike  - but I think "flawless" **is** "perfect"!

Comment: Yes, but the OP said he wanted a different term to avoid repetition.

Comment: @PointlessSpike - but I've convinced him that he was wrong.  :-))

Answer (score 18):

Other words often used in connection with complexion are:

A [radiant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/radiant?&o=100074&s=t) complexion

> **adjective**
>
> 1 emitting rays of light; shining; bright: 
>   the radiant sun; radiant colors.
>
> 2 bright with joy, hope, etc.: 
>   radiant smiles; a radiant future.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

and also...

A [clear](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clear?s=t) complexion (which the OP mentions, but possibly alludes to a very narrow interpretation). "Clear" is often used to denote beauty through purity in respect of a complexion.

> **adjective**
>
> 3 without discoloration, defect, or blemish: 
>   a clear complexion; a clear pane of glass.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: Thanks Marv. But `clear` doesn't connote attractiveness, like I said in the post. `Radiant` might, but not primarily.

Comment: Well "clear" in and of itself doesn't, but it is commonly used in connection with "complexion" and when used in this way the combination *is* taken to mean, as I said, beauty through purity. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the usage note. I think `clear` would indeed be a great _second_ adjective in my sentence. +1.

Comment: @TusharRaj Please note specifically that "radiant complexion" is something of a stock phrase, connoting beauty. https://www.google.com/search?q="radiant+complexion" It's widely used and may be your best option.

Comment: @recognizer: Right on both counts. However, IMO, using radiant puts emphasis on the glow of the skin. This might be me being anal, but I'll avoid words like those if I can

Answer (score 12):

I proffer, without actually specifying any color-

**Fresh, glowing, healthy, lovely, perfect**.

> She had dark and abundant hair, so glossy that it threw off the
>   sunshine with a gleam, and a face which, besides being beautiful from
>   regularity of feature and **[richness](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=The%20young%20woman%20was%20tall%2C%20with%20a%20figure%20of%20perfect%20elegance%20on%20a%20large%20scale.%20She%20had%20dark%20and%20abundant%20hair%2C%20so%20glossy%20that%20it%20threw%20off%20the%20sunshine%20with%20a%20gleam%3B%20and%20a%20face%20which%2C%20besides%20being%20beautiful%20from%20regularity%20of%20feature%20and%20richness%20of%20complexion%2C%20had%20the%20impressiveness%20belonging%20to%20a%20marked%20brow%20and%20deep%20black%20eyes.%20She%20was%20ladylike%2C%20too%2C%20after%20the%20manner%20of%20the%20feminine%20gentility%20of%20those%20days%3B%20characterised%20by%20a%20certain%20state%20and%20dignity%2C%20rather%20than%20by%20the%20delicate%2C%20evanescent%2C%20and%20indescribable%20grace%20which%20is%20now%20recognised%20as%20its%20indication.%20And%20never%20had%20Hester%20Prynne%20appeared%20more%20ladylike%2C%20in%20the%20antique%20interpretation%20of%20the%20term%2C%20than%20as%20she%20issued%20from%20the%20prison.%20&gbv=2&oq=The%20young%20woman%20was%20tall%2C%20with%20a%20figure%20of%20perfect%20elegance%20on%20a%20large%20scale.%20She%20had%20dark%20and%20abundant%20hair%2C%20so%20glossy%20that%20it%20threw%20off%20the%20sunshine%20with%20a%20gleam%3B%20and%20a%20face%20which%2C%20besides%20being%20beautiful%20from%20regularity%20of%20feature%20and%20richness%20of%20complexion%2C%20had%20the%20impressiveness%20belonging%20to%20a%20marked%20brow%20and%20deep%20black%20eyes.%20She%20was%20ladylike%2C%20too%2C%20after%20the%20manner%20of%20the%20feminine%20gentility%20of%20those%20days%3B%20characterised%20by%20a%20certain%20state%20and%20dignity%2C%20rather%20than%20by%20the%20delicate%2C%20evanescent%2C%20and%20indescribable%20grace%20which%20is%20now%20recognised%20as%20its%20indication.%20And%20never%20had%20Hester%20Prynne%20appeared%20more%20ladylike%2C%20in%20the%20antique%20interpretation%20of%20the%20term%2C%20than%20as%20she%20issued%20from%20the%20prison.%20&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3...843.843.0.1389.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..1.0.0.MwDG7hP5oec)** of complexion.

Comment: Good suggestions. +1. These would be great if I was describing the effects of a healthy diet! Also, you made me realize that I still haven't read 'The Scarlet Letter' (It has been on my to-do list since I watched 'Easy A')

Comment: +1 the term "glowing" is very often used in skincare ads.

Answer (score 7):

Then, too, one might claim that the person in question was blessed with an “***exquisite***” complexion.

> [**exquisite**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=exquisite+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=exquisite+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.10.2083856...........0.eCiisxQplFI&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: 1. extremely beautiful and, typically, delicate. "*exquisite*, jewel-like portraits";
>
> **synonyms**: beautiful, lovely, elegant, fine; see, Google

Comment: Dude. You're on fire today!

Comment: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+exquisite+complexion%2Ca+flawless+complexion%2Ca+beautiful+complexion&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20exquisite%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20flawless%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20beautiful%20complexion%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: That's for confusing me when I had all but finalized `flawless` :) Seriously though, another incredibly apt suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: wow word for me....A+.

Comment: Between you and me, I went with `exquisite`. But I'm thinking I should let flawless be the accepted answer.

Comment: I just *knew* you'd like that - and it occurred to me LATE, long after the first was racking up rep.  I included it anyway, cause my mind's always working for **you**.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think ***beautiful*** would be the most suitable adjective to indicate that the complexion is... beautiful. (if you don't want to say just plain *good*).

As it appears in William Hogarth's *The Analysis of Beauty, written with a view of fixing the fluctuating ideas of taste*:

> a beautiful complexion

*[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has%20a%20*%20complexion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chas%20a%20*%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20dark%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20fair%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20good%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20sallow%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20brown%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20light%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20fresh%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20ruddy%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20beautiful%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20florid%20complexion%3B%2Cc0)* might give an idea with the wildcard search also (has a * complexion):

[image]

Comment: So it is indeed correct to say that. Thanks. +1. Although `flawless complexion` [rivals its popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+beautiful+complexion%2Ca+flawless+complexion&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20beautiful%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20flawless%20complexion%3B%2Cc0) in recent years

Comment: @TusharRaj: Well, in the end, more flashy words were upvoted and you chose the most upvoted one. In my opinion, flawless is better to describe the skin; but complexion is more than the skin and "beautiful" better defines it. It is also more common in stock phrases.

Comment: That's a bit unfair, since as soon as I saw it, I clearly stated that I'll accept `flawless` unless someone topped it. I know `beautiful` is suitable here, which is what I initially wrote and said in the comments was my last resort. I hesitated, and asked the question, only because `beautiful` sounded a bit too pedestrian here, imo.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I'm not questioning your choice so it's fine. But I thought you were thinking that "beautiful" doesn't fit. So instead of finding a nice adjective only, I gave you further details.

Answer (score 3):

"Her complexion was lovely."
Personally, I'd put the adjective before the noun (She had a lovely/beautiful complexion), which seems to get more hits ([for beautiful and lovely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beautiful+complexion%2Clovely+complexion%2Ccomplexion+was+beautiful%2Ccomplexion+was+lovely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeautiful%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clovely%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplexion%20was%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplexion%20was%20lovely%3B%2Cc0)) than the word order you suggested.

Comment: +1 for `Lovely` (again, I probably won't be using it though). And good suggestion on the order. I was just checking it the way I wrote it. The adjective comes last for emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

I like "luminescent" to describe a complexion.  Radiant implies an emotional context - that of joy or hope.  "Luminescent," rather, refers to light.  Evidently the beauty products industry agrees that "luminescent" has a positive connotation, since an internet search for "luminescent complexion" returned hundreds of links to skin products.

Dewy" is another option. Again, the beauty products industry seems to think so! As "dewy" refers to moisture, I think it also implies youth as skin dries and wrinkles with age. Dew (according to dictionary.com) is often used in comparisons for purity, delicacy, and refreshing qualities. All are generally considered to be positive attributes

Comment: "Dewy" is another option. Again, the beauty products industry seems to think so! As "dewy" refers to moisture, I think it also implies youth as skin dries and wrinkles with age. Dew (according to dictionary.com) is often used in comparisons for purity, delicacy, and refreshing qualities. All are generally considered to be positive attributes.

Comment: I haven't seen "luminescent complexion"  before but I've encountered "luminous" often enough for it to be a catch phrase.

Comment: Hi Tina, I like your suggestion of `dewy`, even if I probably won't end up using it. Please edit your post to add it. +1. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dewy+complexion%2C+dewy+skin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdewy%20complexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdewy%20skin%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Hi. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer. You find the edit/delete links below your answer (grey text). Please delete the second answer, which is redundant now.

Comment: Thanks Tushar.  I'm new to the site (obviously) and haven't figured how to perform many of the functions.  I think I tried to edit my post and could not, but I also had two sign-on's this morning so that could have been the problem.  I'll delete the other answer now. I appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Tina. When you get a moment click on this [Link](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and take the TOUR and also click on the HELP button on the right-side of the title bar and check–out the “HELP CENTER”, if you haven’t already done so. There’s a lot to learn about this site, such as how to ask good questions and provide good answers, all about rep points and the site privileges they confer. You can examine the formatting techniques of any answer by opening the edit button below that answer, being careful to avoid making any unintentional edits, close by clicking save edit.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're talking about a woman's complexion, and a state of flawlessness, you could say she had a **smooth** complexion.  Smooth skin is highly desirable in almost any complexion, and is strongly evocative of a flawless nature(meaning it will carry the same connotation of 'flawless', while saving you from being repetitive).

There's also **soft**, which carries a similar connotation and suggests a gentleness to the touch - though you might want to save that for if the description you're trying to write has someone touching her face to experience this firsthand - otherwise, I'd go with smooth.

Comment: Incidentally, if you need to modify it for skin tone, "her complexion was fair and smooth" works as well as "her complexion was dark and smooth" or "her complexion was tan and smooth", all depending on the actual tone of her skin.  "Green and smooth" might be a little odd, but I won't judge. ;)

Comment: `smooth` is a good suggestion, and +1 for that. However, I still sense your conviction that describing a complexion without giving details is 'empty'. Like I said: details don't matter here. All that matters is that it's 'exquisite', as @LittleEva put it. (Nailed it, rather.)

Comment: @TusharRaj Note that I wrote this answer *before* you wrote that comment. ;) I'm leaving this here, because I think it's still useful, but I won't begrudge you for wanting to use something that's more abstract, especially if it's completely intentional.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of responding when you wrote the earlier comment, but got tied up and it slipped my mind later. Your answer is a good one, and might be useful to others who see this post. You should indeed leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

"Fair" is another word as in "Monday's child is fair of face" in the poem.

Comment: Fair used to be the word for pale. Still is in InE. Ergo, it's not applicable (specifies color).

Comment: @TusharRaj that maybe so in InE but in BrE fair of face is synonymous with pretty.  Although fair haired refers to a colour.

Comment: Consider the quote of the witches in Macbeth "Fair is foul and foul is fair/Hover through the fog and filthy air" and Macbeth's comment "So fair and foul a day I have not seen".  Both are contrasting beauty with ugliness, rather than light and darkness.

Comment: While "fair of face" is synonymous with "pretty," when "fair" is paired with "complexion" it connotes as pale "coloration."

Comment: @TusharRaj, "fair", my guess, will score over every other adjective in the Indian sub-continent....

Comment: @MystiSinha: You know `fair` refers to color here. It's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Her complexion was becoming"?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if something is ['becoming'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/becoming), it denotes that it suits you. Which is why it is mainly used for clothing. To say someone's complexion is 'suitable or appropriate' doesn't seem like the right thing to say; and isn't what I'm going for regardless.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe: Her complexion was buttery.

Comment: "buttery complexion" seems to me to suggest a certain range of colors (light-brown to yellow). Would you mind adding more explanation of how this is a good answer to the original question, which excludes words related to skin color?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to post under this question. It's great that you want to help. However, this answer doesn't really seem to be a full answer. When answering it's best, in the case of [tag:single-word-requests], to give a good explanation why the word you're suggesting is a good one. If necessary quote and reference a dictionary.